# plotly dash, callback with 2 button inputs and a dropdown input

Tags: python, plotly-dash

How can I write a callback such that if button 1 is clicked, do A; if button 2 is clicked, do B; if a dropdown value is changed, do C?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
        html.H1('initial', id = 'h1'),
        html.Button('to upper', id = 'upper button', n_clicks_timestamp = '0'),
        html.Button('to lower', id = 'lower button', n_clicks_timestamp = '0'),
        dcc.Dropdown(options = [{'value':s, 'label': s} for s in ['good','bad']], value = 'good', id = 'set string')
    ])

@app.callback(
         dash.dependencies.Output('h1', 'children'),
         [dash.dependencies.Input('upper button', 'n_clicks_timestamp'), 
          dash.dependencies.Input('lower button', 'n_clicks_timestamp'), 
          dash.dependencies.Input('set string', 'value')],
         [dash.dependencies.State('h1', 'children')]
    )
def update(upper, lower, newstring, currentstring):
    upper, lower = int(upper), int(lower)

    # ???
    # if dropdown changed, return newstring
    # ???

    if upper > lower:
        return currentstring.upper()
    if lower > upper:
        return currentstring.lower()

    return newstring

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Since the dropdown doesn't have a `timestamp` property, there is no way to decide if it is the latest change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the buttons get to be pressed multiple times in your callback? If not, when the callback is triggered by the dropdown, the buttons will have 0 as `n_clicks` and None (or also 0, I don't recall) as `n_clicks_timestamp`. So you can infer that the dropdown triggered the callback, by process of elimination.

If the buttons get to be pressed multiple times, you need to create another callback on the `children` property of a Div containing the buttons, and simply re-instantiate the buttons, so that they will still be at 0 `n_clicks` and timestamp for the next callback.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what you mean by re-instantiate the buttons. Can you set the button's property when your output is something else?

Comment: You can have multiple callbacks with the same input. I am saying you have a callback on the `children` property of the container of the buttons and if the button timestamp is not None you just re-render the buttons by returning them in the callback. Otherwise you just raise `PreventUpdate` on that second callback.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: @giobatta912 some example code here would be beneficial (for newbies like me) :)